# Importing both a module and submodule. Reason to have two imports?

Tags: python, import

I ran across some python code that contains:

```
import os
import os.path
```

In the rest of the code both functions from `os` and from `os.path` are used.

Does importing this way serve any advantage over just importing `os`? It does make it more clear that you intend to use the `os.path` module, but does it also offer performance benefits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not needed at all, nor does it provide any additional functionality.

```
import os
```

The above import gets everything in that module, *including os.path*

Comment: This is the case for os because the os module imports the path module. But not all packages work that way. Some packages expect you to import the submodules you need so that the package doesn't do unneeded imports.